# Indoor positioning without 3rd party devices like beacons

Tags: android, ios, indoor-positioning-system

I am currently looking for an indoor positioning solution provider for my employer and was going through a lot of websites about indoor positioning and navigation. It all seems really interesting.

But, most if not all seem to involve beacons or at least pre-mapping of a place prior to their solution working well there.

I have a few queries that I am hoping the community will be able to help with.

1. Is there a solution which will work well on all iOS devices?
2. Is there a solution which will work well without involving 3rd party devices like beacons?
3. What is the accuracy we can expect? We need <= 10 metres accuracy indoors, in basement, in a crowded area, on a very high floor etc.
4. Is there a solution which will work well without mapping of the place already done. This means, will a solution work well in any unmapped place as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Linkyfi (https://www.avsystem.com/products/lle/) - it works well on all types of mobile devices, doesn't require 3rd party involvement or any additional equipment (beacons) and works well without calibration. Obviously, the accuracy is more precise with the calibration, but the process itself is really easy and effortless.